# PHP/mysql getting average value of a table column

Tags: php, mysql

How do you get the everage of a mysql table column?

for example:

```
id | name | age

0 | name1 | 20
1 | name2 | 33
2 | name3 | 18
3 | name4 | 24
```

I want to get the average of all the ages.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Mysql supports the `avg` function, which returns the average value.

`SELECT avg(age) as average_age FROM tablename`

Comment: Thank you so much. didn't know it was that easy!

Comment: also be aware that if you use AVG (or other aggregate functions) with more than one column you need to use GROUP BY to group records against particular column

Comment: Is `avg()` in MySQL faster than returning the results and calculating it with PHP?

Comment: You'd best test this out yourself @JaccoAmersfoort Results will vary on so many levels, maybe your database server is simply faster!